# Cloud Foundry triggers if application was created

Tags: cloud-foundry

is there a possibility that cloud foundry triggers an function if a new application was pushed to the platform.

I would like to trigger same internal functions like registration on the API gateway. I know that I can pull the information from events API https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/224/events/list_all_events.html. But, is it also possible by push?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of to what you're asking is the profile script.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile

The note about the Java buildpack not supporting `.profile` scripts is incorrect.  It's a platform feature, so all buildpack's support them.  The difference with Java apps is that you're probably pushing a JAR or WAR file so it's harder to make sure the file is placed in the correct location.  Location of the file is everything.

When your application starts, the platform will first run the `.profile` script, if it exists, that is packaged with your application.  It's a standard shell script and you can do whatever you like in this file.

The only caveat is that your application will not start until this script completes successfully (i.e. exit 0).  Thus you have a limited amount of time for that script to run **and** your application to start.  How much time, you ask?  That is configured by `cf push -t` and is in seconds.  You can also set it in your manifest.yml with the `timeout` attribute.

> Time (in seconds) allowed to elapse between starting up an app and the first healthy response from the app

This is also something that each application needs to include.  I suppose you could also use a custom buildpack to add that file, if you wanted to have it added across multiple applications.  There's no easy way to add it for all apps though.

Hope that helps!